# Nested include sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have three relations with association like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(Course, { as: 'courses', through: CourseUser, foreignKey: 'userId' });
Course.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'users', through: CourseUser, foreignKey: 'courseId' });
CourseRole.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'users', through: CourseUser, foreignKey: 'roleId' });
User.belongsToMany(CourseRole, { as: 'course_roles', through: CourseUser, foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

I'm trying to do a nested include to find all user in a course and their roles.

```
const course = await Course.findOne({
    where: { id: courseId },
    include: [{ model: CourseUser, as: 'organization_users' }, { model: CourseRole, as: 'course_roles' }]
  });
```

But it does not work, I did many research but perhaps dont have a way to do this type of include in sequelize?

Comment: Could you please add table structure?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the result of your query?

Comment: It said CourseRole is not associated with Course, it's true. Is there any way to do the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use **required: true** when loading course while finding roles which include users include courses.

```
const roles = await CourseRole.findAll({
    include:  [
                { 
                    model: User,
                    as: 'users',
                    include:[{
                        model: Course,
                        as: 'courses',
                        where: {id: courseId},
                        required: true
                    }]
                }
            ],
  });
```